# Why Does This Loop Only Take the First Value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

So I'm trying to scrape the company names and stock prices from the "Most Active" section from URL in the code below and store it all in a list. I was thinking of using a loop so it'll grab all of them, but it's only getting the first company and its stock price for some reason. It seems that regardless of if I get it to search for 'tbody' or not, it'll return the same single company and price instead of looping through that entire section of the webpage. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
stock_list = []
url='https://markets.on.nytimes.com/research/markets/overview/overview.asp'

response = requests.get(url)
if not response.status_code == 200:
    print(respose.status_code)

results_page = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
key_data=results_page.find('table',class_="stock-spotlight-table",id="summ_vol+")
key_data2=key_data.find_all('tbody')

def pull_active(url):
    for i in key_data2:
        label = i.find('a', class_='truncateMeTo1').get_text()
        value = i.find('td', class_='colPrimary').get_text()
        stock_list.append((label, value))
    print(stock_list)

pull_active(url)
```

Comment: Are you certain this collection contains more than one item?  It might be working as advertised.

Comment: @J.Murray Use View Source and you'll see lots of matches.

Comment: Make sure that there is no dynamic content loading happening there. Try printing `key_data` block and manually check whats there. Always compare your results with view source.

Comment: I'm sure you will - but are you setting a breakpoint in your Python code and seeing whats in ***that*** collection?

Comment: @J.Murray So I'm looking at the site and in that section currently, it has GE, AMD, PG&E, Fiat, and so on along with their respective stock prices. When I run this code, it only returns the first company and its price (in this case, GE). If I run `print(key_data2)`, I can see that all the other companies are listed under there too. I need it to get the rest of those companies.

Comment: @Poojan Yup, I just tried running both `print(key_data)` and `print(key_data2)` and both of them contain all the info that I need. I'm thinking the <tr> sections might be breaking it, but I'm not sure how it would.

Answer (score 1):

you're looping over all the tables, but not looping over all the items in each table.

```
def pull_active(url):
    for i in key_data2:
        for td in i.findall('td', class_='colText'):
            label = td.find('a', class_='truncateMeTo1')
            value = td.find('td', class_='colPrimary')
            if a and col:
                stock_list.append((label.get_text(), value.get_text()))
    print(stock_list)
```

Comment: So I just tried this and it's now giving me a `'NoneType' object is not callable` error.

Comment: Need to add checking in case the items aren't found

Comment: Doing that gives me a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'` error. No worries though, I managed to fix it just by changing the value variable to `value = i.find('td', class_='colPrimary')` instead of `td.find`. Not 100% sure why it did, but regardless, thanks for getting me to the answer!

Comment: That's what yo did in the original code. But that only finds the first one in the table.

Comment: No, I meant keeping the exact format you have now, but only changing the value one to `i.find` (the label is still using `td.find`). I just ran the edited version and it gave me all of the values I'm looking for.

Comment: That will use the same `value` for all the `label` in the same `tbody`.

Comment: Here's the result that I got from using that modified version: `[('General Electric Co', '10.11'), ('Advanced Micro Devices Inc', '33.13'), ('PG&E Corp', '6.14'), ('Fiat Chrysler Automobiles NV', '14.98'), ('Neuralstem Inc', '1.83'), ('AT&T Inc', '38.20'), ('GrubHub Inc', '34.00'), ('Mattel Inc', '12.02')]`. The values are all correctly associated with their respective companies (which is what I wanted). Might just be pure coincidence that this worked out the way that I needed it to though.

Comment: Sounds like you should post your final code as an answer, I might not be understanding your comments.

Comment: Will do, thanks again for helping me get to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
stock_list = []
url='https://markets.on.nytimes.com/research/markets/overview/overview.asp'

response = requests.get(url)
if not response.status_code == 200:
    print(respose.status_code)

results_page = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
key_data=results_page.find('table',class_="stock-spotlight-table",id="summ_vol+")
key_data2=key_data.find('tbody').find_all('tr')

def pull_active(url):
    for i in key_data2:
        label = i.find('a', class_='truncateMeTo1').get_text()
        value = i.find('td', class_='colPrimary').get_text()
        stock_list.append((label, value))
    print(stock_list)

pull_active(url)
```

key_data2=key_data.find_all('tbody')

This is the line that is causing issues in your solution.
 table row represents each item. So you need to find all the rows and iterate throught that

Comment: There's more than one `truncateMeTo1` and `colPrimary` in each `tr`.

Comment: @Barmar I just ran this one too and it gives me the same answer as yours does, it works as well. Just curious now about which one would be more efficient though.

Answer (score 0):

Basing off of the answer by @Barmar , I was able to get a slightly different solution to this as well.

```
def pull_active(url):
    for i in key_data2:
        for td in i.find_all('td', class_='colText'):
            label = td.find('a', class_='truncateMeTo1').get_text()
            value = i.find('td', class_='colPrimary').get_text()
        stock_list.append((label, value))
    print(stock_list)
```